# Java change cell content instead of creating new cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a list of variables in an excel file which I use as input for an online app and generate a result. That occurs successfully however when I try to save the output in that same file by adding a new column and cells, the original content of the file would be deleted. I only want to add the info to the same document but the only option I found by googling is to create another file.

just to clarify:[Variables for input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDCsf.png)
and instead of just adding the info this happens [Changed document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMOno.png).

How can I fix it without adding more parameter and re-adding the info?

```
@Keyword
public void demoKey(String name) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C://Users/i2srsm/Desktop/New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Data for full set");
    int columnNumber = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
    int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    sheet.createRow(firstRow).createCell(columnNumber).setCellValue('Proposta');
    for (int rn=(firstRow); rn<=lastRow; rn++){
        Cell cell = sheet.createRow(rn).createCell(columnNumber+1)
        cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue(name);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://Users/i2srsm/Desktop/New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear from your question, what you are trying to do. Please add more details. For example: what is the purpose of the `for` loop? What do you mean under "rea-adding the info" ? If you don't change the column - it's value will be persisted when you save the workbook.

Comment: The `sheet.createRow` does exactly what it tells. It **creates** a new empty row. Do using [Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) instead and only if that returns `null`, then do creating the row new.

Answer (score 0):

don't use a `sheet.createRow(row index)` for update the existing excel file. this one create a new row. if you want to update the existing row in a sheet, firstly get related existing row and then create a new cell.

for get existing row

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(row index);
```

for create a new cell in above existing row

```
Cell cell = row.createCell(cell index);
```

try with this

```
sheet.getRow(firstRow).createCell(columnNumber).setCellValue("Proposta");

for (int i=(firstRow+1); i<=lastRow; i++){
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(columnNumber);
    cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue(name);
}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/LifeStyle/Documents/output.xlsx");
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```